# Can we generate Cypher Queries from Visual Model of Property Graph of Neo4j?

Tags: user-interface, neo4j

Is there a way to generate cypher queries from simply modeling the nodes, relations and properties in visual tool ?

Something similar to generating java code from UI Mockups in JFormDesigner or any GUI Builder  like glade for GTK based things.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but maybe it helps anyway:

With Structr, you can either import a GraphGist, or create schema nodes and relationships with their properties in a visual tool.

Structr then creates a schema by auto-detecting labels, types and properties, and provides REST resources for every type which could be determined.

More information can be found in my recent blog post: http://structr.org/blog/graph-gist-importer

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. At least so far.

In [SylvaDB](http://testing.sylvadb.com/) we are working to provide a visual query builder to compose queries. The idea is pretty similar to Query By Example (see an example of an implementation for Django, [django-qbe](http://versae.github.io/qbe/)), but building graph patterns with constraints by drag & drop. Although is still in development, I've attached a picture of the [image: work in progress].