# Generate Cypher Query from Visual model

Tags: user-interface, neo4j, cypher

I am looking if there is a way (maybe using a library or if neo4j supports this), to generate a Cypher query from a Visual Model of a query.

This is what I mean, I may have a visual query (which I am creating myself say using zoomcharts) in my app which looks like this:

[screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avEkb.png)

This query looks for *all persons who live in city Vienna*.

Of course I can get list of nodes and their relationships say as JSON data out of this visual model.

What I want is from this to generate a Cypher query (out of this visual model and say the JSON data I generate from the visual model).

Do you know if there is a tool or library (or maybe it is supported by neo4j in some way) to help me achieve this?

---

IMHO my question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397065/can-we-generate-cypher-queries-from-visual-model-of-property-graph-of-neo4j), however that one is 4 years old and doesn't contain much helpful info.

Answer (score 2):

If you use arrows to create your visual model, you can export it to Cypher :

http://www.apcjones.com/arrows/#

[image]

Comment: is this a library? No I am using zoomcharts in my front end app to generate the visual query

Comment: Ah then it won't work I guess, I have my own front end app which has the visual tool built in (I am creating it using zoomcharts)

Comment: Not clear whether it is already released but neo4j appears to be working on providing this type of tools https://neo4j.com/graphconnect-2018/session/visual-cypher

Answer (score 2):

Such a query can be represented as a sequence of matches for nodes and relationships:

```
MATCH (N0:`Person`)
MATCH (N1:`City` {`name`:"Vienna"})
MATCH (N0)-[R0:`lives in`]->(N1)
RETURN *
```

And this can easily be built from JSON:

```
const nodesMatch = []
graph.nodes.forEach(function(n) {
  const nodeVar = 'N' + n.id
  const nodeLabels = '`' + n.labels.join(':') + '`'
  nodesMatch.push(
    'MATCH (' + nodeVar + ':' + nodeLabels + ')'
  )
})
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/mx9hmdq4/ ]

P.S. I also recommend that you pay attention to `popoto`:

> Visual query builder for Neo4j graph database - https://github.com/Nhogs/popoto